# AWS postgres rds auto switch between primary and read replica

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS RDS, currently my team is using Postgres with read replica(asynchronous). The problem is this read replica is never used. We have Django application, where it using primary DB URL to connect. We want to utilize this this replica for reading the DB and primary for writing from same Django application without having to maintain multiple URLs in code(primary and replicas URLs). Is this possible to handle it on AWS to use appropriate DB based in read or write query?

I need to check if this solution possible, but I am not able getting documentation anywhere. I would appreciate if some one guides me on this topic.

Comment: Are you using 'normal' PostgreSQL on Amazon RDS, or are you using Amazon RDS **Aurora** for PostgreSQL?

Comment: Hi John, its normal postgresql.

Comment: Your app would somehow need to distinguish which URL to use. Typically, a `SELECT` query can go to a Reader Node and everything else to the Writer Node. See: [Load-balancing PostgreSQL queries between read-only and read-write instances | by Gajus Kuizinas | Medium](https://gajus.medium.com/load-balancing-postgresql-queries-between-read-only-and-read-write-instances-fcf30d77933d)

Comment: Also useful: [Is it possible for certain queries that are read-only to hit the read replicas in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77927289/174777) (the concept is similar)